# Restrict server side files from outside

Tags: node.js, express

We develop a project in nodejs,expressjs but not using express-generator for creating the scaffold.We create every folder or file manually.So the problem we face now that we can able to access server side code eg package.json,app.js from outside like when I give "http://localhost:3000/package.json".The file is displayed in browser which is not possible if we use express-generator .Suggest some way so that only public folder will be accessable from outside not other folder just like express-generator.

Comment: Maybe this article may come handy - https://medium.com/hack-your-career/a-few-words-about-security-in-node-js-unauthorized-access-to-filesystem-b9d4f17487d8

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're using `express.static()` with an incorrect root path, namely your project directory instead of just the subdirectory that contains the public files (JS, CSS, HTML, etc).

If your public folder is called `public`, use that as root:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

If your client-side files are set up so they require a `/public` prefix, you can use this:

```
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```